# Reading a matrix in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I try to read and re-write a matrix that has only a particular series of columns. For instance I have an `11 x n` matrix and I want to rewrite it in a `2 x n` matrix with only columns 2 and 3.

```
program fluxXYlambda
implicit none

INTEGER*8::n,i
REAL*8,ALLOCATABLE::dati(:,:)

open(10,file='test.txt')
n=0

do
    read(10,*,end=100)
    n=n+1
end do
100 continue
rewind(10)

allocate(dati(11,n))

open(12,file='coordXY.txt')

do i=1,n
    read(10,*) dati(4,i),dati(5,i)
    write(12,*) dati(4,i),dati(5,i)
end do

end program flussiXYlambda
```

The file `coordXY.txt` is created but is empty.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the value of `n` to see if it's as you expect?  Also, your `read(10,*) dati(4,i),dati(5,i)` isn't reading the second and third columns of `test.txt`.  Can you clarify the layout of `test.txt`?

Comment: @ francescalus yes, is reading the 4th and 5th, it's only an example with a file of 10 columns and i want to take the 4th and 5th (it's the same if i want take the 2th and 3th) the logical steps do not change. `n` is whatever it's the numbers of lines in the file. I count them in the first do cicle

Comment: It isn't reading the fourth and fifth columns either, but the first and second.  Where you put the read numbers doesn't affect the reading. If you want to read those columns you'll need something like `read(10,*) dati(1:5,i)`.  Arguably it may also be better if you could change the question so that it matches your example code.

Comment: my guess your n is zero for some reason, otherwise you'd get something in the output file.  Write out the value of n to check.

Comment: Aside from the syntax error of different a different file name at the end, your code runs for me and puts data into the output file you specified.  Now, it's wrong due to the error that @francescalus points out.  But if you fix that, the code will be working and doing what you want it to.  Maybe you're not locating the correct output file.  Or your compiler could be ignoring something because of a pre-existing blank file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solve the problem thanks to @francescalus.

The command `read(10,*) dati(1:5,i)` read the matrix dati till the column 5 and than i can save particular columns of it. Thanks a lot !